# Replacing a sequence of real numbers with another sequence

Tags: functional-programming, scala

I have a simple task:

> Given a sequence of real numbers, replace all of its members larger
>   than Z by Z and count the number of replacements.

I solved this task using Scala, but my code looks like imperative-style code. I want to make my code more functional. How can I rewrite my program so it becomes functional-style code?

```
def main(args : Array[String]) {
    println("Enter Z number: ")
    val z = readDouble();

    println("Enter the length of sequence: ")
    val lenght = readInt();

    var seq: List[Double] = List();

    // Filling sequence
    for (i <- 1 to lenght) {
      println("Enter sequence item № " + i)
      val item = readDouble();
      seq = item :: seq;
    }

    // number of replacements
    var substituteCount = 0;
    //replacing all numbers larger Z by Z
    seq = seq.map(x => {if (x > z){substituteCount+= 1; z} else x})

    println("Replacement count: " + substituteCount)
    println("New sequence: " + seq.reverse.mkString(" "))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's split this up a bit; firstly, let's put the sequence filling code in its own function:

```
def populateSequence(length: Int): IndexedSeq[Double] = {
  for {
    i <- 1 to length
    _ = println("Enter sequence item ? " + i)
    item = readDouble()
  } yield item
}
```

This utilizes the a combination of `for` and `yield` - in this case, this returns an `IndexedSeq[Double]`, but don't worry, you can treat this like a `List` (or simply convert it to one with a `.toList` if you really want to.

Our code structure then looks like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println("Enter Z number: ")
  val z = readDouble();

  println("Enter the length of sequence: ")
  val length = readInt();

  val seq = populateSequence(length)
```

Ok, where to from here? Well, in this case, instead of modifying `substituteCount` as we go, I'd rather just calculate it up front:

```
val substituteCount = seq count (_ > z)
```

To get our modified `List` (or `IndexedSequence`), we can use another for expression. Again, one thing to remember is that both `for` and `if` are expressions in Scala, so we can do this:

```
val modified = for {
  v <- seq
  item = if (v > z) z else v
} yield item
```

We can then print everything as usual:

```
println("Replacement count: " + substituteCount)
println("New sequence: " + modified.mkString(" "))
```

Comment: Thank you, very nice, especially this statement: `val substituteCount = seq count (_ > z)` :) But does `val modified =...` is better than using `map` method as in my code? I thought that the only one place in my code written in true functional style is usage of `map` method :)

Comment: `map` and `for`-expressions are actually exactly the same - under the covers, `for` gets converted into a `map`. But yeah, whichever way you prefer really - using `map` there is totally fine too.